# Array of numbers giving NaN when trying to multiply Number(value)

Tags: javascript

I tried everything here - why does my total in amountArr become NaN when I multiply Numbers to the array?

```
let amountArr  = [];
for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {

    // Find Data
    let lineAmount  = 0;
    let selected = printArr.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.property == propertyArr[0] && obj.year == fromYear && obj.month == i+1;
    })

    if (selected.length) {

        console.log("typeof (selected[0].amount): " + typeof(selected[0].amount))
        console.log("selected[0].amount: " + selected[0].amount)

        lineAmount = Number(selected[0].amount);
        console.log("typeof (lineAmount): " + typeof(lineAmount))
        console.log("lineAmount: " + lineAmount)

    }

    amountArr[i] += Number(lineAmount)
    console.log("typeof (amountArr[i]): " + typeof(amountArr[i]))
    console.log("amountArr[i]  :" + amountArr[i])
    console.log("-------------------------------------------")

}
console.log(amountArr)
```

And this is the result of console.log

[image]

Any help would be great, I really do not get this one ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you use

```
amountArr[i] += Number(lineAmount)
```

which means

```
amountArr[i] = amountArr[i] + Number(lineAmount)
```

but `amountArr[i]` is undefined and when you add an undefined value to a number it will become `NaN`.

You have to assign some default value to your array `amountArr`

Answer (score 5):

```
amountArr[i] +=
```

This is adding to an undefined value.

Comment: Awwwww!!!  Ok I didnt see that one at all :)  - I did a for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {amountArr[i] = 0;} and now everything works - Thanks Quentin :)